# What is the correct statement of the Bounded Convergence Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

I have obtained this statement of the Bounded Convergence Theorem, I have been told that it is incomplete, that the step of the limit in the integrals is missing, if this is true, what is the correct form of the Bounded Convergence Theorem please?
The statement of the bounded convergence theorem is as follows: let $(\Omega ,\mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a space of finite measure and for all $n$ let$f_n:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ a measurable function such that $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere and $|f_n|\leqslant K$ almost certainly for all $n$, for some $K>0$. Then $f\in L_1(\mu)$ and $f_n \to f$ in $L_1(\mu)$.

Comment: I don't get what is supposedly missing from the statement. What does 'the step of the limit in the integrals is missing' mean?

Comment: It could be that the person who told you this just wanted to hear that $f_n\to f$ in $L_1(\mu)$ [also implies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement) $\int f_n\,d\mu\to \int f\,d\mu$.